# Magento 2.4.3 Docker setup on Linux

Tags: magento2, docker

I am thinking about magento 2.4.3 docker setup.
Has anyone tried
https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento
on linux ?

What's the best docker linux magento setup on linux ?

Comment: Yes Mark Shust's docker setup is the officially referenced Github page by Adobe. So use it or steal parts of it and make your own. That's what I did.

Comment: Can you please guide me thorough steps of it ?
i meant add steps as answer ? That would be very helpful

Comment: Gritting below errors
sudo curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markshust/docker-magento/master/lib/onelinesetup | bash -s -- magento.test 2.4.3-p1
mv: cannot move 'compose/.vscode' to './.vscode': Directory not empty
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/html/magento2/.git/

Comment: I used this video to initially set up my environment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTXRYKRldiU But then adjusted it to newer PHP version. Here are some more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VLSaceaDnM https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUlWqxwzku4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9Tux0xBnrk